# Drawing GeoJson polygon in arbitrary coordinate system

Tags: geojson, d3, three-js

I have a GeoJson polygon I am trying to draw in a 3d scene using d3 and three.js

I have done this before when the polygon was represented in lat, lng coordinates,
but in my case the coordinate system is just integers between -10 and 10 for both x and y.

```
var path = d3.geo.path().projection(d3.geo.equirectangular().center([0,0]))
var contour = transformSVGPath(path(geoJSONObject));
```

However if I add this object to my scene, it is translated far away from its center (0, 0)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that when applying d3 projections, there is a default translation of [480, 250].

This can be overridden by setting the translation manually:

```
var projection = d3.geo.equirectangular();
projection.center([0,0]);
projection.translate([0,0]);
```